# Neo4j - Match a pattern with multiple mandetory nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `:Post` nodes that have multiple `:Tag` nodes connected with `:HAS_TAG` relationships.

All `:Tag` nodes have a property called `name` which is the name of a particular tag.

[image]

So, One post will have multiple tag nodes connected to the post with `:HAS_TAG` relationships.

Now, i want to query all posts that have **all** tags which will be provided at the runtime.

For example, i want to find all **Posts** that have '**HONDA**' and '**BIKES**' tags.

I tried `MATCH (p:Post)-[r:HAS_TAG]-(t:Tag) WHERE t.name in ['BIKES','HONDA'] RETURN p`. But it also returns posts that have only one of the provided tag names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect all the tags for each post and then check if all the required tags are present in that list.

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[r:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag)  
WITH p, collect(t.name) as tags 
WHERE ALL(tag in ['BIKES', 'HONDA'] WHERE tag IN tags)  
RETURN p
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-all